# how to get the total number of all words in corpus?

Tags: java, lucene

For example, there are 3 documents in a collection, document 1 has 25 words, document 2 has 30 words, and document 3 has 54 words. I use Lucene to index the collection. Now, How can get the total number of words in the corpus? (return 109)

Answer (score 0):

You can get the terms for a field with [Fields.terms](https://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/core/org/apache/lucene/index/Fields.html#terms(java.lang.String)) and the number of terms with [Terms.size](https://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/core/org/apache/lucene/index/Terms.html#size()).

```
fields.terms("field").size()
```